# Can the product of only some of the algebraic conjugates be an integer?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose I know that $x_1,\dots, x_n$ are algebraic conjugates and suppose that their product is a rational integer:
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\in \mathbb{Z} $$

Is it possible that there exists some other conjugate $x_0$ such that $x_0\neq x_i$ for any $i=1,\dots,n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example.

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity.
Then $\zeta \cdot \zeta^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: Ok this definately works. But can it happen when they are not roots of unity?

Comment: Isn't $\zeta^{-1}$ the conjugate of $\zeta$?

Comment: @Michelle *Definitely.*

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: $\zeta^{-1}$ is _the_ complex conjugate of $\zeta$ but this is not the meaning used in the question. It is also _an_ algebraic conjugate of $\zeta$ (over $\Bbb Q$), but there are two more of them; the latter fact makes that this example answers the question (yes, it is possible...).

Comment: @Marcvanleeuwen any source on what is meant by an "algebraic conjugate"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Algebraic conjugates (over a given base filed) are algebraic elements in an extension field with the same minimal polynomial. For instance all $\phi(k)$ primitive $k$-th roots of unity (for fixed $k$) are algebraic conjugates, because the $k$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi(k)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, and has those elements as roots.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)=1$$